# android - how to catch touch event like game: World Search

Tags: matrix, textview, touch, android-linearlayout

I have a game like WorldSearch on Store, I tried using this solution:
I created matrix by array of `TextView` and added `TouchEvent` on each `TextView`. Then I caught event by `MOTION.UP`, `MOTION.DOWN`. When I touched on a `TextView` and dragged it, although it went thought other `TextViews` but I just could get event of first `TextView`.
Here is code:

```
private void createMetrix(){

    // amound of item in a row and column
    int itemNum = 10;

    // calculate size of item
    ScreenDimension screenDimension = Utilities.getFinalScreenDimension(this);
    int itemSize = screenDimension.screenWidth / 10;

    // mContentLinear has VERTICAL orientation
    // then adding children linear layouts, these layout has HORIZONTAL orientation
    for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
        LinearLayout theItemLayout = createHorizontalLayout(itemNum, itemSize, i);
        mContentLinear.addView(theItemLayout);
    }

}

private LinearLayout createHorizontalLayout(int itemNum, int itemSize, int row) {
    LinearLayout theLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
    theLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    theLinear.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, itemSize));
    for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++){
        // add item metrix into linear layout having HORIZONTAL orientation
        TextView itemTxt = createItemMatrix(itemSize, row, i);
        theLinear.addView(itemTxt);
    }
    return  theLinear;
}
private TextView createItemMatrix(int itemSize, int row, int column) {
    TextView theItemTxt = new TextView(this);
    theItemTxt.setWidth(itemSize);
    theItemTxt.setHeight(itemSize);
    theItemTxt.setTextSize(13);
    theItemTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    theItemTxt.setText("A" + row + "" + column);
    String tag = row + "|" + column;
    theItemTxt.setTag(tag);

    theItemTxt.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
    return theItemTxt;
}
// Listener
private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private Rect rect;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v == null) return true;
        TextView itemTxt = (TextView)v;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                Log.d("TEXT", "MOVE DOWN: " + itemTxt.getText().toString());
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (rect != null
                        && !rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                        v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                    // The motion event was outside of the view, handle this as a non-click event

                    return true;
                }
                // The view was clicked.
                Log.d("TEXT", "MOVE ON: " + itemTxt.getText().toString());
                // TODO: do stuff
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("TEXT", "MOVE OUT: " + itemTxt.getText().toString());
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Does someone have any ideas on this case?

Thanks, 
Ryan

Comment: You will get more constructive answers if you add some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: @Morne: I added my code, please give me any your ideas, thanks so much!